# Network Link Conditioner - Xcode 8.2 - OS X El Capitan

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-elcapitan, xcode8.2

I want simulate a bad network connection on simulator.

I downloaded and installed Additional Tools for Xcode 8.2 (Network Link Conditioner) from this [link](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_8.2/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_8.2.dmg), activated it, and choose the edge connection, but it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone experience this behavior?

Comment: Can you give more clarity on what exactly isn't working? Did you configure it and then turn it on?

Comment: @lostAtSeaJoshua after I installed it, I just turn it on and choose a profile.